# Ansible: Get all the IP addresses of a group

Tags: jinja2, ansible

Let's imagine an inventory file like this:

```
node-01 ansible_ssh_host=192.168.100.101
node-02 ansible_ssh_host=192.168.100.102
node-03 ansible_ssh_host=192.168.100.103
node-04 ansible_ssh_host=192.168.100.104
node-05 ansible_ssh_host=192.168.100.105

[mainnodes]
node-[01:04]
```

In my playbook I now want to create some variables containing the IP addresses of the group `mainnodes`:

```
vars:
  main_nodes_ips: "192.168.100.101,192.168.100.102,192.168.100.103,192.168.100.104"
  main_nodes_ips_with_port: "192.168.100.101:3000,192.168.100.102:3000,192.168.100.103:3000,192.168.100.104:3000"
```

This is what I got so far:

```
vars:
  main_nodes_ips: "{{groups['mainnodes']|join(',')}}"
  main_nodes_ips_with_port: "{{groups['mainnodes']|join(':3000,')}}"
```

but that would use the host names instead of the IP addresses.

Any ideas how this could be done?

**Update**:

looking at the docs for a while, I think this would allow me to loop through all the ip adresses:

```
{% for host in groups['mainnodes'] %}
    {{hostvars[host]['ansible_ssh_host']}}
{% endfor %}
```

But I just can't figure out how to create an array that holds all these IPs. So that I can use the `|join()` command on them.

**Update2:**
I just thought I had figured it out... but it turns out that you cannot use the {% %} syntax in the playbook... or can I?
Well in the vars section it didn't. :/

```
vars:
  {% set main_nodes_ip_arr=[] %}
  {% for host in groups['mesos-slave'] %}
     {% if main_nodes_ip_arr.insert(loop.index,hostvars[host]['ansible_ssh_host']) %} {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  main_nodes_ips: "{{main_nodes_ip_arr|join(',')}}"
  main_nodes_ips_with_port: "{{main_nodes_ip_arr|join(':3000,')}}"
```

Comment: For anyone using version 2.0+ `ansible_ssh_host` has been deprecated. This solution still works but you need to replace it with `ansible_host`

Comment: You wrote you are not too happy with your own anser. You have been pretty close to the best practice. Please set McKelvins as the accepted one now. https://stackoverflow.com/a/39932728/2898712 Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work on my own now. I'm not too happy about the solution, but it will do:

```
main_nodes_ips: "{% set IP_ARR=[] %}{% for host in groups['mainnodes'] %}{% if IP_ARR.insert(loop.index,hostvars[host]['ansible_ssh_host']) %}{% endif %}{% endfor %}{{IP_ARR|join(',')}}"
main_nodes_ips_with_port: "{% set IP_ARR=[] %}{% for host in groups['mainnodes'] %}{% if IP_ARR.insert(loop.index,hostvars[host]['ansible_ssh_host']) %}{% endif %}{% endfor %}{{IP_ARR|join(':3000,')}
```

Comment: @McKelvin's answer should be the accepted solution, because it's far superior to this one and the recommended way by the Ansible official documentation to do it.

Answer (score 100):

I find the magic `map extract` [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/15157).

```
main_nodes_ips: "{{ groups['mainnodes'] | map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_host']) | join(',') }}"
main_nodes_ips_with_port: "{{ groups['mainnodes'] | map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_host']) | join(':3000,') }}:3000"
```

An alternative(idea comes from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150910230524/https://support.ansible.com/hc/en-us/articles/201957817-In-a-template-get-all-the-IPs-of-all-machines-in-a-group)):

```
main_nodes_ips: "{{ groups['mainnodes'] | map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_eth0', 'ipv4', 'address']) | join(',') }}"
```

(Suppose the interface is `eth0`)

Comment: Note that the alternative only works if all servers have all the main interface set to eth0

Comment: and note also that `ansible_ssh_host` has been renamed `ansible_host` since ansible 2.0

Comment: If you need to add some suffix to each item in the result list (for example, the port number) you can use: 
`"{{ groups['backend_servers'] | map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_host']) | map('regex_replace', '^(.*)', '\\1:80') | list }}"`

Comment: For the second part `ansible_default_ipv4` might be more reliable, since interface names have become unpredictable....

Answer (score 15):

i came across this problem a while back and this is what i came up with (not optimal, but it works)

```
---
# playbook.yml
  - hosts: localhost
    connection: local

    tasks:
      - name: create deploy template
        template:
          src: iplist.txt
          dest: /tmp/iplist.txt
      - include_vars: /tmp/iplist.txt

      - debug: var=ip
```

and the template file is

```
ip:
{% for h in groups['webservers'] %}
 - {{ hostvars[h].ansible_ssh_host }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Creating a task for that seems a bit overkill.

Answer (score 9):

This do the trick for me. Not relying on the interface name

```
- main_nodes_ips: "{{ groups['mainnodes'] | map('extract', hostvars, ['ansible_default_ipv4', 'address']) | join(',') }}"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
- name: Create List of nodes to be added into Cluster
  set_fact: nodelist={%for host in groups['mygroup']%}"{{hostvars[host].ansible_eth0.ipv4.address}}"{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}

 - debug: msg=[{{nodelist}}]

 - name: Set Cluster node list in config file
   lineinfile:
         path: "/etc/myfonfig.cfg"
         line: "hosts: [{{ nodelist }}]"
```

as results you will have the following line in config file:

```
hosts: ["192.168.126.38","192.168.126.39","192.168.126.40"]
```

Answer (score 2):

I've done this by using ansible facts in a playbook.
This playbook takes ansible_all_ipv4_addresses list and ansible_nodename (which is actually fully qualified domain name), iterates through all hosts and saves the data in localpath_to_save_ips file on your localhost. You can change localpath_to_save_ips to the absolute path on your localhost.

```html
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  gather_facts: yes

  tasks:
  - name: get ip
    local_action: shell echo {{ ansible_all_ipv4_addresses }} {{ ansible_nodename }} >> localpath_to_save_ips
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the "only way" to acceess other group's ip's, when any of the following is true:

- some members are not bootstrapped by ansible yet
- using serial
- group is not part of playbook

Is as follows:

```
{% set ips=[] %}{% for host in groups['othergroup'] %}{% if ips.append(lookup('dig', host)) %}{% endif %}{% endfor %}{{ ips }}
```

Requires dnspython on the machine running ansible, install via

```
sudo apt-get install python-dnspython
```

If anyone knows a better way given the conditions, I'd love to get rid of this abomination.

Answer (score 1):

this is what I did in order to not be relied on `eth0` (thanks to ADV-IT's answer):

```
- name: gathering facts
  hosts: mainnodes
  gather_facts: true

- hosts: mainnodes
  tasks:
    - name: Create List of nodes
      set_fact: nodelist={%for host in groups['mainnodes']%}"{{hostvars[host]['ansible_env'].SSH_CONNECTION.split(' ')[2]}}"{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem getting the IP address of a node in another group.
Using a construct like:
  `the_ip: "{{ hostvars[groups['master'][0]]['ansible_default_ipv4'].address }}"`
works only when running the group `master`, which was not part of my playbook (I was running on localhost).
I have overcome the problem by adding an extra play to playbook, like:

```
- hosts: master
  gather_facts: yes
  become: no
  vars: 
    - the_master_ip: "{{ hostvars[groups['master'][0]]['ansible_default_ipv4'].address }}"
  tasks:
  - debug: var=the_master_ip
  - set_fact: the_ip={{ the_master_ip }}
```

After which I can use the `the_ip` in the next play of the playbook.

This may also solve the abomination mentioned by @Petroldrake ?

Comment: strangely enough I was not able to get this to work elsewhere.
In the end I used a solution using `hostvars` taken from https://serverfault.com/questions/962040/sharing-ansible-variable-between-plays

Answer (score 0):

##Just fetch Ip's using -ansible_default_ipv4.address- & redirect to a local file & then use it

- name: gathering_facts
  hosts: hosts
  gather_facts: true
  tasks:

  - name: Rediret to the file
    shell: echo "{{ansible_default_ipv4.address}}" >>ipss.txt
    delegate_to: localhost

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).