# Using ssh-keyscan in shell module does not produce any output in Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm trying to follow [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30226113/ansible-ssh-prompt-known-hosts-issue/35213839#35213839) to add use the `shell` module and `ssh-keyscan` to add a key to my known_hosts file of a newly created EC2 instance.

After trying to do this multiple ways as listed on that question I eventually ran just the ssh-keyscan command using the `shell` module without the append. I am getting no output from this task:

```
- name: accept new ssh fingerprints                                         
  shell: ssh-keyscan -H {{ item.public_ip }}
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash     
  with_items: "{{ ec2.instances }}"
  register: keyscan
- debug: var=keyscan
```

Debug here shows nothing in `stdout` and `stdout_lines` and nothing in `stderr` and `stderr_lines`

Note: I tried running this with the `bash` as the executable shown after reading that the `shell` module defaults to `/bin/sh` which is the `dash` shell on my Linux Mint VirtualBox. But it's the same regardless.

I have tested the shell command with the following task and I see the proper output in `stdout` and `stdout_lines`:

```
- name: test the shell
  shell: echo hello
  args:
    executable: /bin/bash
  register: hello
- debug: var=hello
```

What is going on here? Running `ssh-keyscan` in a terminal (not through Ansible) works as expected.

**EDIT:** Looking at the raw_params output from debug shows `ssh-keyscan -H x.x.x.x` and copying and pasting this into the terminal works as expected.

Comment: So what is **the exact command** that Ansible executes? And what is the result when you run this exact command interactively? Isn't it faster and easier to check the realty on your system than on StackOverflow.

Comment: I have already looked at the raw_params output in debug which runs `ssh-keyscan -H  x.x.x.x` and copied and pasted this into the terminal and had it work as expected

Comment: Maybe you had looked, but no one on SO did, so why do you expect others to know?

Comment: I didn't realize that wasn't clear and didn't expect others to know... sorry, I edited the question

Comment: No. That adds nothing. Voting to close.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late
https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that it doesn't  work the *first* time. While researching [another method](https://fullmetalhealth.com/spin-off-ansible-ssh-bastion-host-dynamic-infrastructure-aws-gathering-ssh-public-key-aws-system-log/) I stumbled across the `retries` keyword in ansible that allows a retry of whatever command. I tried this and on attempt number 2 in the retry loop it is working.